# Prism 7.0 RegisterSingleton not working?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, module, unity-container, prism

I am developing a menu service for my application using Prism 7 and Unity 5.  The app is WPF, MVVM, modular.

The main menu is a module that is assigned to a region.  The menuService keeps track of what menu selections are available and implements the menu object.  The menu module registers the menuService as a singleton:

```
public void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry) {
     containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IMenuService, MainMenuService>();
}
```

In OnInitialized it resolves the menuService and 
registers the permanent menu selections.

```
        IMenuService menu = containerProvider.Resolve<MainMenuService>();
        menu.AddTopLevelMenu(fileMenu);
        menu.AddTopLevelMenu(toolMenu);
        menu.AddTopLevelMenu(helpMenu);
```

When other modules are instantiated I'm using DI to pass in the menuService instance so they can add any additional menu selections.  Everything is working, except that the menuService instance being passed to the other modules is a new one, not the one that was initialized in the MenuModule.  I have tried using constructor injection and an injection method.  They both produce the same result.

I have verified that modules are being instantiated in the proper order. I have browsed the container registry and the menuService is registered with ContainerControlledLifetimeManager.

I can't figure out what I'm missing.  Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IMenuService, MainMenuService>();
```

registers `MainMenuService` as singleton implementation of `IMenuService`.

```
containerProvider.Resolve<MainMenuService>();
```

resolves an instance of `MainMenuService`. Which is different from *the implementation registered for IMenuService*, and in fact not registered at all, and of course also not registered as a singleton. Even if you registered `MainMenuService` as a singleton, it would be a *different* singleton from the singleton registered to implement `IMenuService`.

Long story short - resolve `IMenuService` and you're fine:

```
containerProvider.Resolve<IMenuService>();
```

Comment: Solved the problem.  Thanks a lot!  I'm a bit confused though, how the container was able to resolve MainMenuService in the way that it did since it was not registered.  Is this intended behavior?  Is there any documentation that would shed light on how this works?

Comment: Unity will always resolve concrete types, even without registration (and that should be explained somewhere in the docs). Other containers may behave differently, though.

Comment: This is unexpected for people who, like me, worked with old Unity (2.0). In those older versions, what @BobSculley did would work. E.g., if you said `RegisterType<IMyInterface, MyImp>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())`, you could resolve `MyImp` and get a singleton. I understand in this case, you should really be resolving the interface, but the old behavior made sense too, and I used it all the time from tests to resolve mock implementations.